# Qt text editor on picture

Tags: text, editor, wysiwyg, qtextedit, qgraphicsscene

I haven't found an exact question on this.

I have a picture, it could be blank for the sake of the example, or contain something that I want to add a fancy caption to. I want to add text editing means (akin to Photoshop) on top of the picture.

I'm thinking about subclassing `QGraphicsScene` and placing a subclassed `QTextEdit` object on the scene upon pressing a text placement button. Then, when you click on this object, in addition to editing the text, additional text editing tools become available - so you can set parts of text to bold, italic, modify color, size, etc. And then you would be able to change the object's position - and I think that's available in `QGraphicsScene` by default. And for the background `QBrush`, there would be a background picture.

Is this a reasonable solution?

Maybe there are any ready-available examples of this, but I haven't found them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

**Text item:**
For the text item, I used `QGraphicsScene` with a subclassed `QGraphicsTextItem`. For the background picture, I used a `QGraphicsRectItem` with a `QBrush` and a loaded picture using `QImage` methods.

**To edit parts of the selected text in this subclassed QGraphicsTextItem:**
`QTextCharFormat` applied to my subclassed `QGraphicsTextItem` using `QGraphicsTextItem::textCursor().mergeCharFormat(...)`. This way I can change formatting, such as boldness, italics, etc. on the selection only.

**Some more thingies:**
To pan and zoom around the scene, I used an excellent guide by Vpicaver complete with source code from http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QGraphicsView:_Smooth_Panning_and_Zooming